# mount smb share from other computer

Tags: linux-mint, samba, smb

help needed.
I want to give thunderbird access to local folder on other computer.
So I granted the local user /bin/mount and /usr/sbin/mount.cifs in sudoers.
This works fine, using a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=buebe -o pass=bue //buechers-vorn/thlocalfolder '/home/buebe/.thunderbird/nx1jxvuk.default/Mail/Local Folders'
thunderbird
```

But I cannot get it running via fstab on boot. I tried several things, like

```
//buechers-vorn/thlocalfolder '/home/buebe/.thunderbird/nx1jxvuk.default/Mail/Local Folders' cifs user=buebe,pass=bue,_netdev 0 0
```

where _netdev should be the right argument for waiting until network is started. But I added this later. Also without this it doesn't work. Cannot figure it out. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `Local Folders` in fstab to `Local\ Folders`, Then elimininate both ''

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I did like you said, but still no success.

Comment: You can use your script in your `rc.local`

Comment: (NOTE: Accepted this answer because of the 2nd comment) Ha ! Very good idea, it will work. Thanks.